# How to mix between mixed types (managed & unmanaged) in C++/CLI?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have C++ code (support CLR in the properties) - and I created some unmanaged class. 
Now, I want to create object of this class in the Entrypoint (the interface that exposes) of the code.

But I get the message 'mixed types are not supported'

So - how can I do it?

Comment: How exactly are you using the unmanaged class? As a local variable, a field, a parameter, a return value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without some code this is a really broad question. I hope you can find some answers [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/branbray/archive/2005/07/20/441099.aspx)

Comment: It would be more useful if you added the useful parts of the article you link to to your answer. If the link breaks, your answer would currently become useless.